# Using ccache in automated builds on Docker cloud

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-cloud, ccache

I am using automated builds on Docker cloud to compile a C++ app and provide it in an image.
Compilation is quite long (range 2-3 hours) and commits on github are frequent (~10 to 30 per day).

Is there a way to keep the building cache (using ccache) somehow?

As far as I understand it, docker caching is useless since the compilation layer producing the ccache will not be used due to the source code changes.
Or can we tweak to bring some data back to first layer?

Any other solution? Pushing it somewhere?

---

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# CACHE_TAG is provided by Docker cloud
# see https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/advanced/
# using ARG in FROM requires min v17.05.0-ce
ARG  CACHE_TAG=latest

FROM  qgis/qgis3-build-deps:${CACHE_TAG}
MAINTAINER Denis Rouzaud <denis.rouzaud@gmail.com>

ENV CC=/usr/lib/ccache/clang
ENV CXX=/usr/lib/ccache/clang++
ENV QT_SELECT=5

COPY  . /usr/src/QGIS

WORKDIR /usr/src/QGIS/build

RUN cmake \
 -GNinja \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
 -DBINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL=ON \
 -DWITH_STAGED_PLUGINS=ON \
 -DWITH_GRASS=ON \
 -DSUPPRESS_QT_WARNINGS=ON \
 -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF \
 -DWITH_QSPATIALITE=ON \
 -DWITH_QWTPOLAR=OFF \
 -DWITH_APIDOC=OFF \
 -DWITH_ASTYLE=OFF \
 -DWITH_DESKTOP=ON \
 -DWITH_BINDINGS=ON \
 -DDISABLE_DEPRECATED=ON \
 .. \
 && ninja install \
 && rm -rf /usr/src/QGIS

WORKDIR /
```

Comment: can you share the Dockerfile that you're using for the build? this could help

Comment: Docker file added

Comment: Where are stored cache data? Inside `/usr/src/QGIS` directory?

Comment: ccache data is save in ~/.ccache by default

Comment: @denis-rouzard: I've updated the answer, give it a try

Answer (score 2):

You should try saving and restoring your cache data from a third party service:
- an online object storage like Amazon S3
- a simple FTP server
- an Internet available machine with ssh to make a `scp`

> I'm assuming that your cache data is stored inside the ´~/.ccache´ directory

#### Using Docker multistage build

From some time, Docker supports [Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) and you can try using it to implement the solution with a single Dockerfile:

> Warning: I've not tested it

```
# STAGE 1 - YOUR ORIGINAL DOCKER FILE CUSTOMIZED
# CACHE_TAG is provided by Docker cloud
# see https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/advanced/
# using ARG in FROM requires min v17.05.0-ce
ARG  CACHE_TAG=latest

FROM  qgis/qgis3-build-deps:${CACHE_TAG} as builder
MAINTAINER Denis Rouzaud <denis.rouzaud@gmail.com>

ENV CC=/usr/lib/ccache/clang
ENV CXX=/usr/lib/ccache/clang++
ENV QT_SELECT=5

COPY  . /usr/src/QGIS

WORKDIR /usr/src/QGIS/build

# restore cache
RUN curl -o ccache.tar.bz2 http://my-object-storage/ccache.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xjvf ccache.tar.bz2
COPY --from=downloader /.ccache ~/.ccache

RUN cmake \
 -GNinja \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
 -DBINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL=ON \
 -DWITH_STAGED_PLUGINS=ON \
 -DWITH_GRASS=ON \
 -DSUPPRESS_QT_WARNINGS=ON \
 -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF \
 -DWITH_QSPATIALITE=ON \
 -DWITH_QWTPOLAR=OFF \
 -DWITH_APIDOC=OFF \
 -DWITH_ASTYLE=OFF \
 -DWITH_DESKTOP=ON \
 -DWITH_BINDINGS=ON \
 -DDISABLE_DEPRECATED=ON \
 .. \
 && ninja install

# save the current cache online
WORKDIR ~/
RUN tar -cvjSf ccache.tar.bz2 .ccache
RUN curl -T ccache.tar.bz2 -X PUT http://my-object-storage/ccache.tar.bz2


# STAGE 2
FROM alpine:latest
# YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC TO CREATE THE FINAL IMAGE WITH ONLY REQUIRED BINARIES
# USE THE FROM IMAGE YOU NEED, this is only an example
# E.g.:
# COPY --from=builder /usr/src/QGIS/build/YOUR_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin
# ...
```

In the stage 2 you will build the final image that will be pushed to your repository.

#### Using Docker cloud hooks

Another, but less clear, approach could be using a Docker Cloud `pre_build` hook file to download cache data:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=> Downloading build cache data"
curl -o ccache.tar.bz2 http://my-object-storage/ccache.tar.bz2 # e.g. Amazon S3 like service
cd /
tar -xjvf ccache.tar.bz2
```

> Obviously you can use dedicate docker images to run curl or tar mounting the local directory as a volume in this script.

Then, copy the `.ccache` extracted folder inside your container during the build, using a `COPY` command before your `cmake` call:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/QGIS/build

COPY /.ccache ~/.ccache    

RUN cmake ...
```

In order to make this you should find a way to upload your cache data after the build and you could make this easily using a `post_build` hook file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=> Uploading build cache data"
tar -cvjSf ccache.tar.bz2 ~/.ccache
curl -T ccache.tar.bz2 -X PUT http://my-object-storage/ccache.tar.bz2
```

But your compilation data aren't available from the outside, because they live inside the container. So you should upload the cache after the `cmake` command inside your main `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN cmake...
  && tar ...
  && curl ...
  && ninja ...
  && rm ...
```

If `curl` or tar aren't available, just add them to your container using the package manager (`qgis/qgis3-build-deps` is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so they should be available).